# Why adding salt and pepper noise must be on grayscale image?

Tags: image-processing

I know if my question is pretty basic but I can't seem to find the answer on the internet. So I want to know the people tend to convert image into grayscale prior to adding salt and pepper noise?

Comment: Welcome to SO. As phrased this question has nothing to do with c++ nor opencv. Please dont tag unrelated tags. On the other hand if you have already c++ code then please show your efforts and provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's implied in the name, salt and pepper are black and white. Noise is always present to some degree in images captured by cameras. As such it is often added to images during testing to check if the solution is robust to real world cases.

Noise in a color image can take two forms, chromatic noise or luminance noise. Luminance noise will be consistent across color channels, chromatic noise will vary by color channel. Chromatic noise is caused by the camera sensor's sensitivities to the various wavelengths of light. Luminance noise is caused by the camera system's electrical "noise floor" which is a product of overall sensitivity.

You can add noise in grayscale or in color, the process is the same. For academic purposes, writing a solution that works on a grayscale image with noise is a similar, though possibly less complex, problem than writing a solution for full color images. Computer vision is often only done on grayscale images, so it is common to test against grayscale images.

Comment: Thanks you for your direct and precise information